# Build Pipeline plugin displaying incorrect pipeline information

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, build-pipeline-plugin

I am using build pipeline plugin in Jenkins.
I have a complex workflow for which I am getting incorrect results via Build Pipeline plugin.
To simplify the case:
I have 4 jobs A,B,C,D
and they are supposed to execute in the following manner:

```
A->B->D
 ->C->
```

i.e. **Job A** would trigger **Jobs B and C,**
B and C should run in *parallel*.
and only after both of them have completed,**Job D** should start.

I have used various options to try and achieve the above but none of them is giving the correct display in Build Pipeline plugin.
I have used MultiJob,Parameterized Triggers, Join Build Flow plugins and was able to achieve the the desired flow.
But the Pipeline never gave the correct display.

This is the display that I am getting in build pipeline view:

```
  A->B->D
   ->C->D
```

which is confusing,to say the least.

I might have missed a trick somewhere,while using the plugin(s).
Any pointers to achieve the above desired view using the pipeline?

Comment: Latest version of the BPP plugin doesn't have this issue. Please share what version of Jenkins and Build Pipeline Plugin you are using.